# DataTables in VisualForce Page, Setting swfPath as Static Resource

Tags: javascript, salesforce, flash, visualforce, datatables

I have been working with the DataTables library in VisualForce and have everything working except for the export features. I followed the sample initialization on the DataTables website, but am getting an error that ZeroClipboard.js is undefined in the TableTools.js file.
However, I have checked and re-checked multiple times and the zeroclipboard.js is listed as a resource in the Chrome.

The only thing I am doing differently, and was not able to determine in adapting the function to VisualForce was how to properly call the swf file. Currently I am hosting the file on a local server and referencing it explicitly in the function. Could this be my issue? The error above does not seem to be related, but it is the only thing left I think after extensive troubleshooting.

Does anyone know how I can make the swf file a static resource in Salesforce and call it that way from the function so the file is on the same server as everything else?

Below is my current function setting up DataTables (Question in reference to the swfPath: call, how do I do this with a static resource?)

```
var oTableTools = new TableTools( oTable, {
    "sSwfPath" : "www.MyWebsite.com/resources/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
    "buttons": [
                "copy",
                "csv",
                "xls",
                "pdf",
                { "type": "print", "buttonText": "Print me!" }
               ]
});
$('#demo').before( oTableTools.dom.container );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by uploading swf file(you can find this in the media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf ) as a static resource in salesforce and then accssesing it

For example

```
 oTable = $('#example').dataTable(
            {
                "iDisplayLength": 20,
                "sDom": '<C><"H"T><"clear"><"H"l>t<"F"ip>',
                "oTableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "{!$Resource.SWF_File}"
                },
                "oColVis": 
                {
                    "activate": "mouseover"
                },
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "bJQueryUI": true, 
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "aaSorting": [[ 2, "asc" ]] ,
                "bLengthChange": false, 
                "bFilter": true
```

Comment: The static resource SWF_File consists copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf